# Syntax and overloading copy constructor

Tags: c++, constructor, overloading, default-copy-constructor

I am new to the topic of overloading copy constructors and I just wanted someone to look at my code for my class and see if I am overloading my copy constructor correctly. It is only using a single string as user input. Also, do I need the '&' or not?

```
class TODO {

private:
    string entry;
public:

    List* listArray = nullptr;
    int itemCount = 0, currInvItem = 0;
    int maxLength = 22; 

    TODO() { entry = ""; };
    TODO(const string& ent) { setEntry(ent); }; // Is this correct?
    void setEntry(string ent) { entry = ent; };
    string getEntry() const { return entry; };

    void greeting();
    void programMenu();
    void newArray();
    void getList();
    void incList();
    void delTask();
    string timeID();
    string SystemDate();
    friend istream& operator >>(istream& in, TODO& inv);
    friend ostream& operator <<(ostream& out, TODO& inv);
    void componentTest();
    void setTask(string a);
    string getTask();
    bool validTask(string a);
    bool notEmpty(string e);
    
    
};
```

Comment: In this code there's no copy constructor whatsoever. [See here what they look like](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/copy_constructor).

Comment: it seems like List probably needs the copy ctor, and that you don't want a dynamically allocated List, and you probably don't want a List at all

Comment: `TODO(const string& ent) { setEntry(ent); };` is not a copy constructor, it's just a normal constructor. A copy constructor would copy a `TODO` object, e,g, `TODO(const TODO& rhs) ...`,

Comment: To be more specific, `TODO(const string& ent)` is a *converting* constructor.

Comment: Why do you use assignment in the default constructor and `setEntry` in the non-default constructor? Also: If you choose the parameter type of `setEntry` as `std::string`, it would probably be better to move the parameter into the member variable to avoid a unnecessary copy; the only scenario where this may be undesireable is one where the member variable is expected to have a higher capacity than the parameter and the member variable possibly growing during the lifecycle of the object by means other than calling `setEntry`.

Answer (score 0):

That's correct, but it's just a constructor of `TODO` taking a const reference to a `string`. You can test it [here](https://godbolt.org/z/69n79nj3T).

Passing `const string& ent` (by const reference) is not a bad idea. Another option would be to pass `string ent` (by value), and move that string when initializing `entry`, i.e. `: entry{ std::move(ent) }`. As [here](https://godbolt.org/z/dzs496Ksa).

The class TODO has a default copy constructor. Check the line at the Insight window [here](https://cppinsights.io/s/c2ed5eb9) (you'll have to click Play first).:

```
// inline TODO(const TODO &) noexcept(false) = default;
```

The default copy constructor would just copy the members, including the `List` pointer, but not the `List` elements (shallow copy). Notice both instances of `TODO` would be pointing to the same `List` elements, and any operation on them would affect both instances.

Should you want to implement a custom copy constructor, the syntax would be (see [here](https://godbolt.org/z/Tr5jnEfoY)):

```cpp
    TODO(const TODO& other) {
        std::cout << "custom copy_ctor\n";
        *this = other;
        // Copy listArray elements
        ...
    }
```